# jqGrid Change the value of a field on beforeShowForm

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-php

I have a grid with a value in a predefined field, I want to do it is to click edit a row want to change the value of one of the fields in the FormEdit.

The ColModel is:

```
    colModel:[
                {name:'id',index:'ID', width:50, hidden:true, search:false, editable:false,resizable:false},
                {name:'product',index:'product', align:"center", width:20, search:false, editable:false,resizable:false},
                {name:'volume',index:'volume', align:"center", hidden:false, width:15, search:false, editable:true}
                ],
```

I would establish volume = 1 when open the edit form, and i do like this...

```
 ondblClickRow: function(id){
                jQuery("#products").jqGrid('editGridRow', id, {
                  recreateForm:true,  
                  beforeShowForm: function(form) { 
                      $('#tr_volume',form).show(); 
                      $("#tr_volume",form).val('1');
                      },
                  reloadAfterSubmit:false, closeOnEscape:true, closeAfterAdd:true, closeAfterEdit:true,
                  editable:true, editrules:{edithidden:true,required:true,number:true,minValue:1}                    
               })
```

But it's not working for me, what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't use `hidden: true` property of `volume` column. So the setting `$('#tr_volume',form).show()` is unneeded. The setting of `$("#tr_volume",form).val('1')` is wrong, because the `<tr>` element have no value. I think that you need jusu use `$("#volume",form).val('1')` or `$("#volume").val('1')` instead. The `<input>` field with the `id="volume"` (the same id like the column name) will be created in the form. It's the field which you probably try to change.